# how to download zip file using php?

Tags: php, html, download, zip

i want to download zip file which is uploaded on google drive.following is my html code for download,

```
 <a class="tlClogo" href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzJrMJ44NPAEV1ZIRmk4VTdxbG8" id="downloadThisPage"  oncontextmenu="return false;" download="myzip.zip"/>Click Here to download</a>
```

this is javascript,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("downloadThisPage").href = window.location.toString();
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking about just downloading, or you do mean you also want to unpack it?

Comment: i am trying to dwnload zip file which is located on google drive and drive link is "https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzJrMJ44NPAEV1ZIRmk4VTdxbG8

Comment: i am asking about download and once download zilp file it should be unpack.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use javascript anchor tag will do the work. You just need to change the link like this.

FROM:

```
<a class="tlClogo" href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzJrMJ44NPAEV1ZIRmk4VTdxbG8" id="downloadThisPage"  oncontextmenu="return false;" download="myzip.zip"/>Click Here to download</a>
```

TO:

```
<a class="tlClogo" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=SYSo&id=0BzJrMJ44NPAEV1ZIRmk4VTdxbG8">Click Here to download</a>
```

Comment: its working but download link open in new tab i want to download in same page

Comment: i.e url should not open it directly download from href

Comment: having any idea?

Comment: is there need to use php how to do that?

Comment: Hi Neeya, I guess it's impossible not to redirect to google page. As you can see the confirm parameter in the url is dynamic and they use cookies for it.

Comment: If you really want to download zip file without redirecting to other page. Using another file sharing site is a good idea. Just my opinion